# Convert Region to Path

Tags: java, swt

Does anybody know if there is a way to convert `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region` object to `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path` one?

I have a method that is returning Regions (different shapes) and I need to draw them in a `Canvas`.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That method that generates the `Region`s, can you not generate the `Path`s in there as well? I don't see any way to convert a region to a path.

Comment: Thank you Baz for your answer, but that method, unfortunately is in another library not managed by me... :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected. I'm afraid there isn't a lot you can do in that case (at least I don't see how).

Comment: The shame here is that we cannot draw "Region"s in Canvas, at least as far as I know...